Continuity of definite integral over a set with continuous boundaries
Let $\alpha,\beta:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions such that $\alpha<\beta$. Let
$D\mathrel{\mathop:}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid a\leq x\leq b,\ \alpha(x)\leq y\leq \beta(x)\},$ and $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function.
Let $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R},\; x\mapsto\int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)}f(x,y)\,dy.$   I think $F$ should be continuous, but I don't know how to prove it.

$x\mapsto \int_a^{x} f(x,y)dy$ is continuous. If you call this  $g$ then your function is $g(\beta (x))-g(\alpha (x))$.

@geetha290krm Why is $x\mapsto\int_a^xf(x,y),dy$ continuous?

That fact (or something very similar) has been proved many times on MSE. It uses uniform continuity of $f$. You need to show your attempt if you want to receive  an answer.

@geetha290krm My attempt is too long and ugly to write in comment. I was wondering if there is a simpler and more beautiful proof. My method does use uniform continuity of $f$, but it also assumes that f can be extended to an open subset containing D.

@GEdgar You are right! Thanks. I will edit it.

Lets prove the continuity of $F$ in $x_0\in[a,b]$
For $x$ in $[a,b]$, define
$$
c = \max(\alpha(x_0), \alpha(x))\\
d = \min(\beta(x_0), \beta(x))\\
$$
$f$ is continuos and $D$ is compact so there exist a $M$ such that $M>|f|$ in $D$.
Note that
$$
\left| \int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{\beta(x_0)} f(x_0, y) \, dy - \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} f(x, y) \, dy \right|= \left| \int_{c}^{d} f(x_0, y) \, dy + \int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{c} f(x_0, y) \, dy + \int_{d}^{\beta(x_0)} f(x_0, y) \, dy - \int_{c}^{d} f(x, y) \, dy - \\ \int_{\alpha(x)}^{c} f(x, y) \, dy - \int_{d}^{\beta(x)} f(x, y) \, dy \right|
$$
$$
= \left| \int_{c}^{d} (f(x_0, y) - f(x, y)) \, dy + \int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{c} f(x_0, y) \, dy - \int_{\alpha(x)}^{c} f(x, y) \, dy + \int_{d}^{\beta(x_0)} f(x_0, y) \, dy - \int_{d}^{\beta(x)} f(x, y) \, dy \right|
$$
Now lets bound $|\int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{c} f(x_0, y) \, dy|$ choosing an appropriate delta.
If $c =\alpha(x_0)$ then $\int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{c} f(x_0, y) \, dy=0$.
If $c =\alpha(x)$, we have, by the continuity of $\alpha$, that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exist a $\delta_1$ such that if $|x_0-x|<\delta_1$ then $|\alpha(x)-\alpha(x_0)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{5M}$, so:
$$
|\int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{\alpha(x)} f(x_0, y)dy| \leq \int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{\alpha(x)}| f(x_0, y)|dy<\int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{\alpha(x)}Mdy=M|\alpha(x)-\alpha(x_0)|<\varepsilon/5
$$
In any case for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exist a $\delta_1$ such that if $|x_0-x|<\delta_1$ then
$$
|\int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{\alpha(x)} f(x_0, y)dy|<\varepsilon/5
$$
In a similar way we can bound  $|\int_{\alpha(x)}^{c} f(x, y) \, dy|$, $|\int_{d}^{\beta(x_0)} f(x_0, y) \, dy|$ and $|\int_{d}^{\beta(x)} f(x, y) \, dy |$ choosing appropriate deltas.
Now lets bound $| \int_{c}^{d} (f(x_0, y) - f(x, y)) \, dy|$ choosing an appropriate delta.
Its know that the function
$$
g(x)=\sup_{y\in [c,d]}(|f(x_0,y)-f(x,y)|)
$$
is continuos in $[a,b]$ (because $|f(x_0,y)-f(x,y)|$ is continuos) and $g(x_0)=0$.
So for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exist a $\delta_2$ such that if $|x_0-x|<\delta_2$ then
$$
|f(x_0,y)-f(x,y)| \leq \sup_{y\in [c,d]}(|f(x_0,y)-f(x,y)|)<\frac{\varepsilon}{5l}
$$
for every $y\in [c,d]$ (where $l=\max_{x\in [a,b]}\beta(x)-\min_{x\in [a,b]}\alpha(x)$).
Then:
$$
| \int_{c}^{d} (f(x_0, y) - f(x, y)) \, dy| \leq \int_{c}^{d}|  (f(x_0, y) - f(x, y)) | \, dy<\int_{c}^{d}\frac{\varepsilon}{5l} \, dy<\frac{\varepsilon(d-c)}{5l}<\frac{\varepsilon}{5}
$$
So if we take $\delta$ as the minimun of all the deltas above, if $|x_0-x|<\delta$ then
$$
\left| \int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{\beta(x_0)} f(x_0, y) \, dy - \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} f(x, y) \, dy \right|=
\left| \int_{c}^{d} (f(x_0, y) - f(x, y)) \, dy + \int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{c} f(x_0, y) \, dy \\ - \int_{\alpha(x)}^{c} f(x, y) \, dy + \int_{d}^{\beta(x_0)} f(x_0, y) \, dy - \\ \int_{d}^{\beta(x)} f(x, y) \, dy \right|\\
 \leq | \int_{c}^{d} (f(x_0, y) - f(x, y)) \, dy| +| \int_{\alpha(x_0)}^{c} f(x_0, y) \, dy |+ |\int_{\alpha(x)}^{c} f(x, y) \, dy |+ |\int_{d}^{\beta(x_0)} f(x_0, y) \, dy|\\ + |\int_{d}^{\beta(x)} f(x, y) \, dy |<\frac{\varepsilon}{5}+\frac{\varepsilon}{5}+\frac{\varepsilon}{5}+\frac{\varepsilon}{5}+\frac{\varepsilon}{5}=\varepsilon
$$

Maybe it is just me, but I find your proof hard to follow...

That's true, my proof was difficult to follow. I just made some edits to clarify a few things. Please let me know if you have any questions.

The following proof is probably the same as Chris's in essence, but I used Tietze extension theorem to extend the domain of $f$ to a nice rectangle containing $D$ to avoid the technicalities arising from the domain of $f$.
By the extreme value theorem, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are bounded; say $|\alpha|,|\beta|\leq M$ for some positive real number $M$.
Let $R\mathrel{\mathop:}=[a,b]\times[-M,M]$. Then $D\subseteq R$, and
by the Tietze extension theorem, $f$ can be extended to a continuous function $\hat{f}:R\to\mathbb{R}$.
Note that
$$F(x)=\int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)}\hat{f}(x,y)\,dy.$$
$\hat{f}$ is a continuous function on a compact set, so it is bounded by the extreme value theorem. We may choose $M$ large enough so that $|\hat{f}|\leq M$.
$\alpha,\beta,$ and $\hat{f}$ are continuous functions on a compact set, so they are uniformly continuous.
Hence, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$x_1,x_2\in[a,b],\ \ |x_1-x_2|<\delta\quad\implies\quad|{\alpha}({x_1})-{\alpha}({x_2})|<\epsilon,\quad |{\beta}({x_1})-{\beta}({x_2})|<\epsilon,$$
and
$$(x_1,y),(x_2,y)\in R,\ \ |x_1-x_2|<\delta\quad\implies\quad |\hat{f}({x_1},{y})-\hat{f}({x_2},{y})|<\epsilon.$$
Let $x_1,x_2\in[a,b]$. Then
$$F({x_1})-F({x_2})=\int_{{\alpha}({x_1})}^{{\beta}({x_1})}\hat{f}({x_1},{y})\,d{y}-\int_{{\alpha}({x_2})}^{{\beta}({x_2})}\hat{f}({x_2},{y})\,d{y}.$$
The second integral can be decomposed to
$$\int_{{\alpha}({x_2})}^{{\beta}({x_2})}\hat{f}({x_2},{y})\,d{y}=\int_{{\alpha}({x_2})}^{{\alpha}({x_1})}\hat{f}({x_2},{y})\,d{y}+\int_{{\alpha}({x_1})}^{{\beta}({x_1})}\hat{f}({x_2},{y})\,d{y}+\int_{{\beta}({x_1})}^{{\beta}({x_2})}\hat{f}({x_2},{y})\,d{y}.$$
By the mean value theorem for integral,
$$\int_{{\alpha}({x_2})}^{{\alpha}({x_1})}\hat{f}({x_2},{y})\,d{y}=({\alpha}({x_1})-{\alpha}({x_2}))\cdot\hat{f}({x_2},{y}^\ast)$$
for some $y^\ast$ between $\alpha(x_2)$ and $\alpha(x_1)$, and
$$\int_{{\beta}({x_1})}^{{\beta}({x_2})}\hat{f}({x_2},{y})\,d{y}=({\beta}({x_2})-{\beta}({x_1}))\cdot\hat{f}({x_2},{y}^{\dagger})$$
for some ${y}^{\dagger}$ is between ${\beta}({x_1})$ and ${\beta}({x_2})$.
Hence,
\begin{align*}F({x_1})-F({x_2})&=\int_{{\alpha}({x_1})}^{{\beta}({x_1})}((\hat{f}({x_1},{y})-\hat{f}({x_2},{y}))\,d{y}\\
&\quad-({\alpha}({x_1})-{\alpha}({x_2}))\cdot\hat{f}({x_2},{y}^\ast)-({\beta}({x_2})-{\beta}({x_1}))\cdot\hat{f}({x_2},{y}^{\dagger}).
\end{align*}
It follows that if $|{x_1}-{x_2}|<\delta$, then
$$|F({x_1})-F({x_2})|\leq 2M\epsilon+\epsilon M+\epsilon M=4M\epsilon,$$
i.e., $F$ is continuous.
